# UISplitViewControllerDelegate methods not called when using presentsWithGesture?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

It seems that when  the `UISplitViewController` property `presentsWithGesture` is `YES`, the `UISplitViewControllerDelegate` methods aren't called when the master viewController is shown/hidden using swipe gestures. In particular, `splitViewController:willShowViewController:invalidatingBarButtonItem:` and `splitViewController:willHideViewController:withBarButtonItem:forPopoverController:` aren't being called.

How are the rest of you managing updating state for your view controllers when using your splitViewController with gestures?

Answer (score 1):

The `willHide`/`willShow` methods are for when the master view controller is hidden/shown as the result of an orientation change, and as their parameters suggest, are primarily so that you can add/remove a bar button item for showing the master view controller in a popover. (A split view controller's master popover has a different appearance from other popovers, but it's still a `UIPopoverController`.)

I still see [`splitViewController:popoverController:willPresentViewController:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISplitViewControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UISplitViewControllerDelegate/splitViewController%3apopoverController%3awillPresentViewController%3a) being called when I swipe the master view in. And that popover controller's delegate gets notified when the popover gets dismissed.

Comment: The willShow/willHide are not at all related to orientation changes, at least according to the docs -- *Tells the delegate that the hidden view controller is about to be displayed in a popover...You can use this method to perform any additional steps prior to displaying the currently hidden view controller.*